# Hartshorne Problem I.3.5

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The problem asks to show that if $H$ is a hypersurface of $\mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $d$, then $\mathbb{P}^n - H$ is isomorphic to an affine variety. Following the hint, if we apply the $d$-Uple embedding $v_d : \mathbb{P}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^N$, the hypersurface $H$ is embedded in a hyperplane $h$ of $\mathbb{P}^N$. Then $\mathbb{P}^n - H$ is isomorphic to $v_d(\mathbb{P}^n) \cap (\mathbb{P}^N -h)$. Indeed, $\mathbb{P}^N -h$ is an affine variety, but why does that mean that $v_d(\mathbb{P}^n) \cap (\mathbb{P}^N -h)$ is an affine variety? What is the precise argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ is an affine variety, and $Z$ is a closed subvariety of $X$ in the Zariski topology, then $Z$ is affine. In your case, $v_d(\mathbb{P}^n)$ is closed inside of $\mathbb{P}^N$, hence $v_d(\mathbb{P}^n) \cap (\mathbb{P}^N - h)$ is a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^N - h$.

Comment: Do you assume $X$ is affine ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: I was able to get my edit in seconds before your comment. But thanks for the catch!

Comment: I am sorry but i don't see the truth of your statement. To make sure we are on the same page, i follow Hartshorne's definition, where an affine variety is an irreducible and closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$ in the Zariski topology, for some $n$. If what you are saying is true, then, since $\mathbb{A}^n$ itself is an affine variety, every closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$ is irreducible, which is not the case. Any comments?

Comment: @Manos: A closed *subvariety* of an affine variety is an affine variety (by the way, it is true that every closed subset of an affine *scheme* is again an affine scheme). If you want to see that $v_d(\mathbb{P}^n) \cap (\mathbb{P}^N - h)$ is irreducible, note that it is an open subset of the irreducible set $v_d(\mathbb{P}^n)$

Comment: @Manos: You are correct, then answer has been edited.

Comment: Yes, i figured that, thanks.